Using Pyadomd with Mac (or alternate way to query SSAS)
I'm trying to query data from a SSAS data model. A coworker shared some code what works on Windows and looks pretty similar to the documentation on the pyadomd docs which looks something like this:
from sys import path
path.append('\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET\\ADOMD.NET\\150')

from pyadomd import Pyadomd

conn_str = 'Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=localhost;Catalog=AdventureWorks;'
query = """EVALUATE Product"""

with Pyadomd(conn_str) as conn:
    with conn.cursor().execute(query) as cur:
        print(cur.fetchall())

When running this on a Mac, I received the following error:
RuntimeError: Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would
                    have been "mono" on this system. Either install a
                    compatible runtime or configure it explicitly via
                    `set_runtime` or the `PYTHONNET_*` environment variables
                    (see set_runtime_from_env).

I took this to mean that I should install mono on my computer so I did that with homebrew:
brew install mono
Now, I'm trying to figure out how to make the code use Mono. I'm not sure whether I simply need to change the file path in the path.append() line (to what?), or set some environment variable (what environment variable exactly?). The documentation I've found does not seem to speak to this. I'm completely lost and would appreciate any help!
Alternatively, is there a cleaner way to query SSAS data models from Mac using Python?
Update:
I've since found out that this error is ocurring when importing pyadomd, specifically when pyadomd imports the clr package. I'm playing around with setting different environment variables with no luck. The error above is produced whe importing Pyadomd:
>>> from pyadomd import Pyadomd

RuntimeError: Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would
                    have been "mono" on this system. Either install a
                    compatible runtime or configure it explicitly via
                    `set_runtime` or the `PYTHONNET_*` environment variables
                    (see set_runtime_from_env).

Current code looks like this:
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/opt/homebrew/opt/mono/lib"
>>> os.environ["PYTHONNET_RUNTIME"] = "mono"
>>> from pyadomd import Pyadomd

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the file 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient'.
File name: 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient'

.
.
.

This error is raised when Pyadomd is not able to find the AdomdClient.dll file
The error might be solved by adding the dll to your path. 
Make sure that the dll is added, to the path, before you import Pyadomd.

which produces a new error indicating that I need to add the dll file to my path, however my understanding is .dll files would not exist on a Mac. It's starting to look like it won't be possible to find a workaround for Mac.
